# Trigger to update NumberOfQuantityInstallments field of product2

Tags: apex, before-trigger, trigger

I need to create a trigger on OpportunityLineItem in which the quantity entered by user in OpportunityLineItem should be copied to NumberOfQuantityInstallments field of product2.

I am doing this way

```
trigger UpdateNumberOfQuantityInstallments on OpportunityLineItem(before insert) 
{
   List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
   for(OpportunityLineItem oli : trigger.new)
   {
         oli.id = product2id;
         product2.NumberOfQuantityInstallments = oli.quantity;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmmmmm....I am questioning the value of this trigger.  This means that each time a product is added to an opportunity, the product 2 record would be updated with data from that 1 opportunity product.  This would constantly be overridden by the most recent opportunity product.  What is the value in this?  I think you might be trying to accomplish something else maybe?

Comment: Yes, Chris Duncombe is correct. I too got the fault in the Structure....It is not a best idea to change the Product Fields whenever a Line is added in an opportunity.

Comment: @Subhash what can I do then ??

Comment: Agreed with Chris, i'm a bit confused what the goal is? Also, you don't need a trigger for this, you can use this brilliant app to declaratively create the functionality you want: https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries